# Как вывести подкатегории?

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

Имеется модель категорий

```html
public static function getCategoriesList(){
  $db = Db::getConnection();
  $categoryList = array();

  $result = $db->query('SELECT id, name, sort_order, status, parent_id FROM category '. 'ORDER BY sort_order ASC');

  $i = 0;
  while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
   $categoryList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
   $categoryList[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
   $categoryList[$i]['sort_order'] = $row['sort_order'];
   $categoryList[$i]['status'] = $row['status'];
      $categoryList[$i]['parent_id'] = $row['parent_id'];
   $i++;
  }

  return $categoryList;
 }

  public static function getSubCategoriesList(){
    $db = Db::getConnection();
    $subCategoryList = array();

    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `parent_id` =' . $id);

    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
      $subCategoryList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
      $subCategoryList[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
      $i++;
    }

    return $subCategoryList;
  }
```

Имеется контроллер

```html
class SiteController
{

  public function actionIndex()
  {
    $categories = array();
    $categories = Category::getCategoriesList();

   $subCategories = array();
    $subCategories = Category::getSubCategoriesList();

    $latestProducts = array();
    $latestProducts = Product::getLatestProducts(8);
    
    require_once(ROOT . '/views/site/index.php');

    return true;
  }
}
```

Имеется вывод во view

```html
<ul>
 <?php foreach ($categories as $categoryItem): ?>
  <li>
   <p class="aside__title"><?php echo $categoryItem['name'];?></p>
   <?php echo $categoryItem['id'];?>
   <div class="aside__plus">
    <span></span><span></span>
   </div>
   <ul>
    <?php foreach ($subCategories as $categorySubItem => $id): ?>
     <li>
      <a href="/category/<?php echo $categorySubItem['id'];?>">
       <?php echo $categorySubItem['name'];?>
      </a>
     </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ul>
  </li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Но просто категории выводятся, а подкатегории - нет, в чем проблема?

Comment: вот тут `WHERE `parent_id` =' . $id` $id у вас не задано

Comment: public static function getSubCategoriesList($id) - в функцию я передал аргумент

Comment: он ругается на контроллер

Comment: в коде у вас `  public static function getSubCategoriesList(){` определитесь

Comment: А если ругается, напишите, как ругается. На какую строку

Comment: переписал чтобы функция принимала аргумент

Comment: а можно связаться как то с вами в другом месте, даже за доп плату

Comment: $latestProducts = Product::getLatestProducts(8); на это ругается

Comment: Надо смотреть класс Product. Как ругается?

Comment: а зачем в него смотреть, если надо вывести подкатегории категорий по parent_id

Comment: Уберите `$latestProducts = array();
    $latestProducts = Product::getLatestProducts(8);` если это вам не нужно

Comment: это вывод продуктов на странице

Comment: Если на него ругается, причем тут подкатегории?

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь, из за своей невнимательности не то написал, ругается на - $subCategories = Category::getSubCategoriesList($id);

Comment: А что говорит? Как ругается? полный текст ошиби?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\OSPanel\domains\beauty\controllers\SiteController.php on line 14

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\OSPanel\domains\beauty\models\Category.php:33 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\beauty\controllers\SiteController.php(14): Category::getSubCategoriesList(NULL) #1 C:\OSPanel\domains\beauty\components\Router.php(61): SiteController->actionIndex() #2 C:\OSPanel\domains\beauty\index.php(37): Router->run() #3 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\beauty\models\Category.php on line 33

Comment: вот сюда $subCategories = Category::getSubCategoriesList(ВОТ СЮДА !!!); надо подставить id категории, для которой подкатегории ищете

Comment: да я понимаю, если указать id категории для которой нужно получить подкатегории, то функция сработает и выведет их, но мне нужно в цикле каждой категории вывести подкатегории

Comment: $subCategories = Category::getSubCategoriesList(9); выведет подкатегории по parent_id = 9 соответственно

Comment: Где там у вас цикл, перебирающий категории?